# What is the grandchild of a parents's siblings called?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

I know that my parents' siblings' child is my cousin.

But what about the grandchild of my parents' siblings?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The naming of different types of cousins is referred to as “ordinals and removals”.

If you share the same grandparents, you are “first cousins”. If you share the same great grandparents, you are “second cousins”. And so on.

The children of your first cousin are your “first cousins once removed”. The grandchildren of your first cousin are “first cousins twice removed”. The children of your second cousin are your “second cousins once removed”. And so on.

Note that most people have no idea how this system works and just use the generic “cousin” for all distant relatives.

Comment: Note that the system is reflexive, so the grandchildren of your great grandparents who are not children of your grandparents are also first cousins once removed, for example

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Are you just clarifying that the relationship is the same in both directions, or are you covering a case I didn’t?

Comment: @StephenS Yes, you didn't mention the case of the parents of your Nth cousin. That's what I think the other commenter is getting at. Good answer anyway.

Comment: @StephenS I was trying to clarify because without a certain amount of mathematical proficiency I think it appears to be a separate case; that is, when people see 'my cousin's children are my first cousin once removed' they don't necessarily understand that that means you are also their first cousin and similarly you have first cousins who you are the children of a first cousin to.  That you have a first cousin who shares the same grandparents and is their direct ancestor/descendant makes that clear, of course, but it's still good to have a reminder, I think.

Comment: I think most people know “first cousin,” and know the rest aren’t. What they *are*, that’s a mystery to most, but it’s not all that unusual to specify “first cousin,” or to specify “distant [read: not first] cousin,” or often in casual conversation “second cousin or cousin removed or something like that I don’t know how it works,” to indicate that the cousin *isn’t* a first cousin.

Comment: The way I think of it is that the ‘cousin number’ specifies the _horizontal_ distance between the people (as seen in a family tree), and the ‘removal number’ gives the _vertical_ distance.

Comment: I wouldn't say "cousin" for all distant relatives, but I would just say "cousin" for all relatives of the same generation. I'd more likely call my parents' cousins (i.e. of the same generation as my parents) "uncle"/"aunt" (or the Tamil equivalents of those words), and similarly I'd address those of my grandparents' generation as "grandma"/"grandpa" (or rather, the Tamil equivalents). I suspect similar terms of address are common in other Indian families as well. (I didn't understand the whole "X cousin Y removed" terminology for the longest time, growing up in the US...)

Comment: This is the only answer that gives the correct answer: Nobody uses this system in colloquial speech. It is good to know to **understand** but unless you are talking to a doctor or a geneticist, just call all your distant relatives "cousins".

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil: Wait, what? So "first cousins once removed" could be either "the children of your first cousin" (one generation younger) or the "grandchildren of your great grandparents" (one generation older)? Shouldn't it be "first cousins once added" or something like that, if they are one generation older? If you insist on "first cousins once removed" being reflexive, doesn't it break the definition and renders it ambiguous?

Comment: @EricDuminil Reflexive just means that if *you* are *my* first cousin once removed, then *I* am also *your* first cousin once removed.

Comment: @StephenS: Yes, and that's what bothers me. If you are my "first cousin once removed", it apparently means that you are either one generation older or one generation younger than me. How can it be reflexive? It would be like saying that if you are my uncle, I'm your uncle too! What's the point in using a long, technical term which many people don't understand ("first cousin once removed"), if it doesn't specify the generation and basically could mean "someone or their grandchildren"?

Comment: @EricDuminil If I am one generation older than you, my grandchildren would be your second cousins once removed. If I am one generation younger, my grandparents wouldn’t be your cousins at all.

Comment: @StephenS: Sorry, my last statement was incorrect. What I meant is that two of my "first cousins once removed" can be separated by two generations, but indeed cannot be grandparents/grandchildren. "If I am one generation younger, my grandparents wouldn’t be your cousins at all". One of your grandparents would be my aunt or uncle, right?. Do we agree that "first cousin once removed" can either mean "child of first cousin" or "parent of second cousin"? PS: Your answer is good, BTW, I'm only complaining about the ambiguity of the term, not about your explanation.

Comment: @EricDuminil The point of the system is to provide a rough measure of consanguinity within noble/wealthy families trying to monitor/manage inbreeding. Unless you are looking for dates at your family reunion, everyone there is just “a cousin”.

Comment: @StephenS: It makes sense for this purpose. Thanks for the explanation, I'll stop bothering you. :D

Comment: @StephenS I am a native English speaker. From England. I am 46 years old. I have degrees from one of the finest of our ancient universities. I literally had no idea what a first cousin once removed was until I read your answer just now. I know "thanks" comments are frowned upon, but thanks!

Answer (score 25):

The grandchild of your parent's sibling is your first cousin once removed. (You are also their first cousin once removed.)

Here's another attempt at a diagram, simply because this form works better for me, maybe it will for you too. The number of "removals" are the extra generations on one side only (shown in orange below), and once those extra generations are removed, the degree indicates how many more generations to get back to siblings (shown in blue below).

[image: Diagram of degrees of cousins and removals]

Comment: This diagram deserves to be the accepted answer, it's perfect

Answer (score 13):

The standard [family tree chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQK7a.png) never made a lot of sense to me, so I drew the following "ladder picture", where first cousins, seconds cousins, third cousins, and so forth, are rungs on a ladder:

[image]

This visual might be easier for some folks to understand.  To answer your specific question:

> what about the grandchild of my parents' siblings

- You are Person 3.
- Your parent's sibling is Person 2.
- The grandchild of Person 2 is Person 6.

**Person 3 and Person 6 are first cousins once removed.**

Answer (score 2):

The **child** of an aunt or uncle is your

- (first) cousin

The **grandchild** of an aunt or uncle is your

- first cousin once removed

Please see the chart at [What Is a Second Cousin?](https://www.familysearch.org/blog/en/what-is-a-second-cousin/)

Comment: Informally, you could say "my cousin's child" and be understood immediately, and for more complicated relationships "a *distant* cousin".

Comment: That comment is the only useful answer.  "My cousin's child" is far clearer and less ambiguous than all this "removed" business.

Comment: @JamesK to me it seems to imply that the person in question is not an adult (likewise "cousin's son/daughter"). If they are an adult, they'd have to be "cousin once removed", "distant cousin", "cousin" or something else

Comment: This question has gone right off topic. This is an English site, not genealogy.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some good stuff on this, e.g.

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:European_kinship_system_en.svg for English
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:European_kinship_system_de.svg for German.

My German wife had an awful lot of aunts (Tanten) and uncles (Onkel), whereas I have a lot of cousins. It wasn't until I saw these diagrams that I understood why.

See also:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Table_of_Consanguinity_showing_degrees_of_relationship.png (English)
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Table_of_Consanguinity_showing_degrees_of_relationship_zh-hans.png (Chinese)
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Table_of_Consanguinity_showing_degrees_of_relationship_zh-hans.png (Arabic)